# Php errors line is red

Tags: php

I have this code and give error, what is wrong in the formatted code?

```
 $row = intval( $cat_id )( "select cat_path,cat_name from sdb_goods_cat where cat_id=".intval( $cat_id ) );

  $row = intval( $cat_id )( "select cat_path from sdb_goods_cat where cat_id=".intval( $cat_id ) );

 $rs = intval( $catid )( "select tabs,cat_id from sdb_goods_cat where cat_id=".intval( $catid ) );

 $row = intval( $catid )( "select tabs,cat_id from sdb_goods_cat where cat_id=".intval( $catid ) );

  intval( $v )( "update sdb_goods_cat set p_order=".intval( $v )." where cat_id=".intval( $k ) );

  $row = intval( $id )( "SELECT count(*) AS num FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE parent_id=".intval( $id ) );

 $rs = intval( $id )( "SELECT * FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE cat_id=".intval( $id ) );

  $row = intval( $parent_id )( "SELECT parent_id, cat_path, p_order FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE cat_id=".intval( $parent_id ) );

 $sDefine = intval( $data['cat_id'] )( "SELECT parent_id FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE cat_id=".intval( $data['cat_id'] ) );

   $aCats = intval( $catid )( "SELECT * FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE parent_id = ".intval( $catid ) );

  $row = intval( $catid )( "SELECT parent_id FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE cat_id=".intval( $catid ) );

 intval( $catid )( "DELETE FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE cat_id=".intval( $catid ) );
        intval( $catid )( "update sdb_goods set cat_id=\"0\" WHERE cat_id=".intval( $catid ) );
```

The above lines code give error line in Dreamweaver and I dont know why. Please help me to find what to change?

Comment: Aren't they red cause they are in quotes ? :) "," Dreamweaver colors text in quotes. Try running from server

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: mouse over the line...doesn't it say something like "syntax error"? should give you a hint what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you worried about what Dreamweaver says, go and run it on the server. If it works fine there, then there is no problem.

By the way, you should capitalize all reserved keywords of MySQL like "select", "where" and "update".

Comment: @DAN u should not worry with Dreamweaver, that is not a big deal...run on server

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = intval( $catid )( "SELECT parent_id FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE cat_id=".intval( $catid ) );
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do maybe you meant something like this, plus the call should be made like this `$a = intval($b);` the () parentheses after would produce a syntax error.

```
$row = mysql_query('SELECT parent_id FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE cat_id='.intval( $catid ));
```

Also as a remark try to avoid using the double quotes if you are not interpolating any variables, the single quotes give indication to your reader that they don't need to search for any interpolation.

Comment: I tryed to remove to add $row = mysql_query('SELECT parent_id FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE cat_id='.intval( $catid )); and this show error in dreamweaver at this code also the server show "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in /homepages/46/core/model_v5/goods/mdl.productCat.php on line 51" for the above php code

Comment: $row = intval( $catid )( "SELECT parent_id FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE cat_id=".intval( $catid ) );

Comment: @Dan: you cannot write sone code as `intval($foobar)("SELECT");`, I think you are copy and pasting the code from a different place

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = intval( $cat_id )( "select cat_path,cat_name from sdb_goods_cat where cat_id=".intval( $cat_id ) );
```

What are you trying to do? It looks like you're taking a variable, converting it to an integer, and then trying to call it like a function with a SQL query. Integers aren't functions, so this won't work. Dreamweaver is probably giving you a syntax error because what you're writing doesn't make sense.

You probably want to use `mysql_query` like RageZ suggests. Rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have done this $row = mysql_query('SELECT parent_id FROM sdb_goods_cat WHERE cat_id='.intval( $catid )); and will not show any more category from the product is added, will show only Home  without category path

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the code you are using is outcome of a blind find and replace. Like most of the guys I am unable to understand what actually you want to write, and as Mark said, use MySQL keywords in Upper case.
IMHO, Dreamweaver is a bad choice for writing PHP code/backend development, I use Netbeans, free and fast and better than DW. DW is an awesome products for front end.